# How to sticky a combobox in the top of sheet with Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, shapes

I have some comboboxes in my excel sheet that allow me to take data from another sheet and insert it in the cells I want, everything works fine.

What I want to do now is fix the comboboxes in their position to have a "sticky" behavior when I scroll down. I wrote a small macro that works with only when I click on a cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange (ByVal Target As Range)
Dim tp As Double
tp = Rows (ActiveWindow.ScrollRow) .Top + 7
ActiveSheet.Shapes ("category"). Top = tp
ActiveSheet.Shapes ("exercise"). Top = tp + 25
End Sub
```

Can I get the same behavior by activating the macro when scrolling with the mouse wheel or when scrolling by moving the scrollbar?

I appreciate any help and thank you for any replies.

Comment: When you say "fix their position", are you trying to get the checkboxes to "float" above the cells when the worksheet scrolls by underneath? In other words that, relative to the worksheet window itself, the checkboxes remain fixed?

Comment: That's right, but it's not a checkbox but a combobox.

Comment: Detecting the window scroll events is possible ( http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DetectScroll.htm ), its quite involved though. Have you considered using a userform (with no border etc) instead of shapes? its not part of the sheet so will stay where you put it.

Comment: It can be a good solution. But I don't have much experience with excel, is there a valid noob proof reference on how to create forms and keep them fixed?

Comment: A [modeless userform](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-userform/#ModelessUserform) is likely the best solution in this case. Your userform can be very small -- only the size of the combobox if you want. You can hide the title bar of the window and other visual elements to customize it as you'd like.